# C# Delegate and Events

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I am working with delegates and events for the first time and help. When the program runs its supposed to show the text in blue if the gpa has increased from the original and red if it has decreased. I have to use two events IncreaseGpaEvent and DecreaseGpaEvent. Have to have a color variable and is assigned in the ToString(). Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
public delegate void UpdateGPADelegate(string ConsoleColor);
class Student
{
    // Fields
    private string studentName;
    private double gpa;
    public string ConsoleColor;
    public event UpdateGPADelegate IncreaseGpaEvent;
    public event UpdateGPADelegate DecreaseGpaEvent;

    // Properties
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public double GPA
    {
        get { return gpa; }
        set
        {
            IncreaseGpaEvent += onUpdate;
            if (!(value > gpa))
            {
                gpa = value;
                IncreaseGpaEvent("Red");
            }
            DecreaseGpaEvent += onUpdate;
            if(!(value < gpa))
            {
                gpa = value;
                DecreaseGpaEvent("Blue");
            }
         }
     }

    public Student(string studentName, double gpa)
    {
        this.studentName = studentName;
        this.gpa = gpa;
    }
   public void onUpdate(double value)
    {
        if (value < gpa)
        {
            ConsoleColor = "Red";
        }
        if (value > gpa)
        {
            ConsoleColor = "Blue";
        } 
    }
    
    public override string ToString()
    {
        string str;
        str = string.Format($"Name: {StudentName} GPA: {GPA}");
        return str;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the issue you are facing?

Comment: You haven't stated what your problem is, but this code is weird. In the setter of `GPA` you add `onUpdate` to the event handler list *on every set*, then you call the event handlers.

Comment: As @Charlieface mentioned you are attaching event handler to on every set which is wrong. I have added answer please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Try This..

```
public delegate void UpdateGPADelegate(double ConsoleColor);
class Student
{
// Fields 
//    private string studentName;
private double gpa;
public string ConsoleColor;
public event UpdateGPADelegate IncreaseGpaEvent;
public event UpdateGPADelegate DecreaseGpaEvent;

// Properties
public string StudentName { get; set; }
public double GPA
{
    get { return gpa; }
    set
    {
        
        if (!(value > gpa))
        {
          
            IncreaseGpaEvent(value);
            gpa = value;
        }
        
        if(!(value < gpa))
        {
            DecreaseGpaEvent(value);
            gpa = value;
        }
     }
 }

public Student(string studentName, double gpa)
{
    this.studentName = studentName;
    this.gpa = gpa;
    IncreaseGpaEvent += onUpdate;
    DecreaseGpaEvent += onUpdate;
}
public void onUpdate(double value)
{
    if (value < gpa)
    {
        ConsoleColor = "Red";
    }
    if (value > gpa)
    {
        ConsoleColor = "Blue";
    } 
}

public override string ToString()
{
    string str;
    str = string.Format($"Name: {StudentName} GPA: {GPA} ConsoleColor: {ConsoleColor}");
    return str;
}
}
```

There were somethings wrong with the code which i have fixed like you were assigning value to gpa after that events were raised which never would be greater or smaller and signature of delegate was also wrong.

Comment: `studentName` is field, but class also have property `StudentName` which always will be null. Field should be removed